# Word for someone who is driven by morality

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who is very driven by morality, constantly trying to do what they believe is morally right.

This word would be used in a sentence like *"I really admire her; she truly
is a (...) person."*

Comment: What is wrong with the word **moral**? Unless you can explain why *it* doesn't fit, there can be nothing other than a list of random synonyms given. (And you can use a thesaurus as easily as any of us for that.)

Comment: She is morality driven.

Comment: I've added a few to supplement the Thesaurus list, but "virtuous" works best for this example, imo

Comment: Everybody is driven by morality, the problem is that every person has their own. So the problem is not the word, but conveying your interpretation of it.

Comment: "[Paragon](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/paragon) of morality" could also work, if they are exceptionally moral, and viewed as an example to follow by others.

Comment: nice suggestion.  [Paragon of virtue](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paragon%20of%20virtue) is more traditional, defined by Merrian-Websters as "a person who has no moral faults".

Comment: I'm fond of the word "probity", but it wouldn't fit in the sentence as it stands. Something like "I really admire her probity" would work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- [righteous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/righteous)

is probably the strongest and most direct

- [scrupluous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scrupulous)

is another important one

- [upstanding](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/upstanding)
- [high-minded](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/high-minded)

are also venerable terms

Comment: Beware that "righteous" and "high-minded" both have some negative connotations.

Comment: @piojo "Self-righteous" is negative, but I believe "righteous" only takes a negative connotation from its context. It's widely used in a positive sense. Do you have some examples to the contrary?

Comment: @piojo agree strongly, re: context.   "Righteous!" has even become a slang term used in the same manner as "awesome!"

Comment: @erickson I may have been projecting my own biases onto "righteous", as that connotation seems to exist more in my head than in things I've read. But certainly it has religious connotations, which must be where my negative impression comes from.

Comment: @piojo Context is everything, as you point out!  Righteous has also found usage in detective fiction.  Specifically, where a cop engages in the extra-judicial killing of a perpetrator, if the perpetrator is known to be guilty, it is known as a "[righteous kill](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=righteous+kill&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crighteous%20kill%3B%2Cc0)".

Answer (score 10):

Roget's Thesaurus offers the following:

- virtuous
- moral
- upright
- ethical
- honorable
- principled
- honest

Those words may have slightly different connotations, but they all essentially mean that the person is trustworthy because of their moral fiber.

Comment: It would be nice to know why this answer was downvoted, since it answers the question and the OP found it helpful. If there is a problem with it, I will be happy to edit.

Comment: This is better than the currently accepted answer, which contains words with negative connotations.

Answer (score 4):

Someone who is zealous about something has a lot of passion for it. Someone who is morally zealous would be someone who is all about sticking to their moral principles:

> I really admire her. She truly is a **morally zealous** person.

Comment: I would say "morally zealous" works, but "moral zealot" (particularly the "zealot" part) can have a negative connotation.

Comment: @ScottM You're right. I'll delete that. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen the word "zealous" used to mean something positive.

Comment: @Nye I guess that has to do with the fact that we tend to think of extremes as something inherently negative.

Comment: @Nye Providing a "zealous defense" is generally considered a positive trait for an attorney.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness:

I assume from your example you are looking for a positive word.  As others have already provided examples of this, I won't add to them.  However there is an expression with a usually negative connotation that fits and hasn't been suggested:

**goody two-shoes**

To paraphrase [Adam Ant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o41A91X5pns):  They don't drink, they don't smoke - what do they do?

Comment: I wouldn't say **goody two-shoes** implies *driven by morality*, but rather that one is insistent on *following the rules*. Morality goes above the rules imposed on us by society or other social or systematical structures.

Comment: @ChickenFeet Possibly, however 'define goody two-shoes' in google gives:  an ostentatiously *virtuous* or well-behaved person, and there's nothing in Mr Ant's lyric suggesting the protagonist is a rule-breaker.  Also I don't think 'rules imposed on us by social structures' and 'morality' are that different in definition.

Comment: I do agree in most cases following the rules also means doing the morally right thing, albeit not always. I would argue morality is derived primarily from philosophy. Philosophy and in-place rules certainly do not define one another.

Answer (score 1):

> I really admire her, she truly is a **good** person.

[MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good):

> 2a (1) : virtuous, right, commendable a good person

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lean towards a negative connotation (which, admittedly, does not fit your example sentence):

[do-gooder](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/do-gooder): A well-meaning but unrealistic or interfering philanthropist or reformer.

---

In German there's also the (rather condescending) word [Gutmensch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmensch) (literally: *good human*) which I thought was in use in English as well, but neither the usual dictionaries nor google ngram know about it..

Comment: [*mensch*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mensch) is frequently used in American English and the term is also found in dictionaries. I "think" you can use it for women too, but maybe you could use it to write a question.